# Access from one linked object to another

Tags: c++

I have a problem in my c++ project. I compile 2 `.cpp` files and linked them to a shared
library `.so`. I want to use a method form one of them to another,but receive `undefined reference vtable *`. Those files have header files. Anyone can provide any hint?

Comment: What compiler are you using and with what settings?

Comment: g++ -Wall   -I.. -I.. -I../libs/ysig -O2 -fno-check-new  -fno-exceptions -fPIC -DHAVE_GCC_FORMAT_CHECK -DHAVE_BLOCK_RETURN  -export-dynamic -shared -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -Wl,--retain-symbols-file,/dev/null  -o regexroute.yate -I../libs/ysig  regexroute.cpp -lyatesig -L.. -lyate

Comment: Do you define the functions you are using in the header files? Read this [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables) about vtables  definitions.

Comment: what do you mean define ? prototype or implementation? yes I define prototype dear. I read this document but not help.

Comment: Make sure all virtual functions have definitions.

Comment: for accessing one of them to other, object files (.o) must be in an archive file (.a) ?

Comment: I have one virtual function that is destructor. and this is implemented.

Comment: Thx for feedbacks.I have 2 shared libraries that they linked to a third library, I want to use a class of one shared library to another one, How I can do this?   I can link to shared library to each other? how?  tx

Comment: It is really hard to tell anything without seeing a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define some method for your class in head file, but forget to implement them in your cpp file. Please check all method for this class(define vs. implement)one by one.